# List view link contains special symbol

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-admin

My `listview` URL appears like this:

```
http://localhost/inventorymanagement/#/~2Finventory~2Frequest~2Fitem~2F/list
```

How do I change it into a readbale form like this?:

```
http://localhost/inventorymanagement/#/inventory/request/item/list
```

Please have a look on my js file.

```
// create an admin application
var admin = nga.application('admin')
  .baseApiUrl(BASE_URL); // main API endpoint
// //create a user entity
// //the API endpoint for this entity will be 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:id
var inventoryItem = nga.entity('/inventory/request/item/');
inventoryItem.listView().fields([
  // use the name as the link to the detail view - the edition view

  nga.field('user_details.email').label('email'),
  nga.field('required_quantity'),
  nga.field('demand_date'),
  nga.field('inventor_item_details.item_title').label('Item Title'),
]).filters([
  nga.field('user_details.email')
  .label('User Filter')
  .pinned(true)
]);
admin.addEntity(inventoryItem)
```

Comment: where is your js ?

Comment: question edited, Please look!

Comment: and for your routing ?

Answer (score 0):

ng-admin uses angular-translate, go and watch it how it works with ng-admin.